# How does exactly Express.js handle errors?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, try-catch

So, the trivial thing. All we know that Express has built-in default error handler that expect four arguments (err, req, res, next) to handle "synchronous exceptions" like ReferenceError, TypeError, etc:

*UPDATE:* this question is Express-specific, not about how to catch unhandled exceptions/etc. I want to know how in the first code block Express can handle user-defined exception. Second example with async. exception doesn't directly belongs to this question.

```js
const express = require('express')();

express.all('*', (req, res) => {
  throw new Error('my own error');
  res 
    .send('okay?');
});

express.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res 
    .status(503)
    .send('Express is still up and running');
}).listen(3000);
```

But not this:

```js
const express = require('express')();

express.all('*', (req, res) => {
  process.nextTick(() => {
    throw new Error('my own error');
  });
  res 
    .send('okay?');
});

express.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res 
    .status(503)
    .send('Won\'t be executed');
}).listen(3000);
```

But I'm curious about the realization of this handler.

I can't find anything like

`process.on('uncaughtException'...` or domains/Promises/cluster.

Maybe I miss something.

Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [catch-all kind of block in Express's router](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/layer.js#L94) that gets executed:

```
try {
  fn(req, res, next);
} catch (err) {
  next(err);
}
```

So in this block all exceptions are catched and translated to `next()` function calls with error parameter set to match the exception.

In more detail, when a request arrives to express:

- [`app.handle()`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L158) is called, which then determines router and calls `router.handle()`
- [`router.handle()`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L136) processes through layers and eventually matches your handler registered with `express.all('*', ...)` signature
- [`handle_request`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/layer.js#L86) (inside router's internal Layer module) calls your handler function as specified in the above try-catch block, effectively catching all possible exceptions and translating them into next calls.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I just made my own 'Express' to reproduce that behavior. Very simple and elegant handling as for me.